# Get Client Local time from GMT offset

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

In my website, I need to keep track of the user's local date/time without relying on Javascript. I have a table where each user's timezone offset in GMT is stored. So, for user X, the timezone offset may be stored as -5.

To get the user's current local date and time, I am using the following code

```
int timeOffsetGMT = -5;
DateTime localTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(timeOffsetGMT);
```

The above snippet of code works but does not account for daylight savings. Any thoughts on how I can factor in daylight savings to my calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int timeOffsetGMT = -5;
DateTime localTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(timeOffsetGMT);

if(TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsDaylightSavingTime(localTime))
    localTime = localTime.AddHours(1);
```

---

To set the `TimeZoneInfo` directly, if your servers don't reside in the "Eastern Standard Time" zone (GMT-5), use the following:

```
var zone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Eastern Standard Time");

int timeOffsetGMT = -5;
DateTime localTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(timeOffsetGMT);

if(zone.IsDaylightSavingTime(localTime))
    localTime = localTime.AddHours(1);
```

---

[MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.isdaylightsavingtime.aspx)

Comment: Is there a way to set the TimeZoneInfo based only on the GMT offset?

Comment: short answer, no. there can be multiple "`TimeZoneInfo`s" in a given offset. Some countries/cultures don't observe DST. you could look into using `TimeZoneInfo.CreateCustomTimeZone` and pass in the appropriate parameters, but you'd still need to know the user's *time zone* beforehand.